# Setting up tap:i18n in meteor project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, meteor, ionic-framework

I'm currently trying to use the meteor package tap:i18n in my project. Unfortunately I'm not able to use it. When I use the underscore variable notation I get an unexpected token error in my browser. Otherwise the meteor app is staring without any errors.

I did not change anything else than described below. Do I have to add the tap:i18n package to my app loader in some way? (Sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm relatively new to meteor - but the tap:i18n docs don't say anything about it)

My document structure is as follows:

```
/
... all the other stuff not relevant for i18n support
/packages/package.js
/packages/package-tap.i18n
/i18n/en.i18n.json
```

I currently use a dummy template (in /client/templates/map.html)

```
<ion-view title="{{ _ 'map_tab_title' }}">

</ion-view>
```

the file en.i18n.json looks as follows

```
{
  'map_tab_title': 'Map'
}
```

the package.js and package-tap.i18n file is as provided in https://atmospherejs.com/tap/i18n#setup-tap-i18n with slight changes due to the language file. Additionally I had to move the files to the /packages sub-directory (and changed the *.i18n.json path accordingly) because otherwise meteor was throwing an error when starting the project.

Comment: Did you run `meteor add tap:i18n` as well?  You must still do this even if you are using a local package (e.g. a package in your `packages` directory)

Comment: Yes I ran this as well. Sorry I forgot mentioning it.

Comment: Do you literally only have those 3 files in your `packages` folder?  If so then that would be an issue...you need the entire tap:i18n package source?  When I use local packages I simply clone the package github repo into a subdirectory (named after the package) in the packages folder.  Then run `meteor add ...`.  Is this more or less what you did?  It's not clear in your question.

Comment: No I do have much more files in the project directory and I have the tab-i18n package there as well (not in the packages directory but in the project folder as it gets automatically copied/downloaded there when I execute meteor add tap:i18n). I just showed the relevant files and directories for clarity and an easier reading of my post.